# Fading banner like text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, recursion, correctness, fading

I have a title text, which I want to fade into a box.
Afterwards, a subtitle should fade in beneath it.
Once both are visible, they should fade out, and the next set should fade in, in the same fashion.

This I have created, however, I have my doubts on how well it runs, that is, if it takes to much CPU for the browser. One of my concerns are also the recursion depth of Javascript.

I have the following code (which I have also included in a jsfiddle, along with CSS and HTML http://jsfiddle.net/ukewY/1/)

```
var no = 3;

function fadeText(id) {
  // Fade in the text
  $("#text" + id).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '+=50'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Upion completion, fade in subtext
    $("#subtext" + id).animate({
      opacity: 1,
    }, 5000, function() {
      // Upon completion, fade the text out and move it back
      $("#subtext" + id).animate({
        opacity: 0, 
      }, 1000, function() {
        $("#text" + id).animate({
          opacity: 0,
          left: '+=200'
        }, 3000, function() {
          // Yet again upon completion, move the text back 
          $("#text" + id).css("left", "19%");
          $("#subtext" + id).css("left", "10%")
          fadeText((id % no) + 1);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fadeText(1);
});
```

My question is if this is the right way to do it; or if there is a better, maybe none-recursive, way of doing this?

PS. As this is for a banner for a website, I do not worry about `id` being to big, as the people have probably moved on since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion seems fine to me, but there are a few other things I spotted:

- You probably want to dynamically read the number of titles, rather than having to specify them at the top of the script.
- You are using the same selectors $("#text" + id) and $("#subtext" + id) twice in each title. You should only do it once, and assign it to a variable. This means you only have one function call, not two.
- You may want to use the eq() selector to eliminate the need for $("text" + id) and make it tidier
- There is a couple of data maps that you are passing to animate() that end with commas even though there is only 1 value (specifically "{opacity: 0,}"). This will cause problems on some browsers.
- I'm not 100% sure, but i think calling a function from within itself is bad, you should use setTimeout (and use an anonymous function if you need to pass the function some parameters to avoid it using eval())
- I know you said it didn't matter, but id getting too big can happen if a user just leaves your page open (e.g. answers the phone then has to rush out). They shouldn't come back to an error.
- You can use $(DO STUFF) rather than $(document).ready(DO STUFF)

I took car of these and took the liberty of tweaking your code to the following:

```
function fadeText() {
    thistext = $text.eq(titleid);
    thissubtext = $subtext.eq(titleid);
    thistext.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '+=50'
    }, 5000, function () {
        thissubtext.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 5000, function () {
            thissubtext.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 1000, function () {
                thistext.animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    left: '+=200'
                }, 3000, function () {
                    thistext.css("left", "19%");
                    thissubtext.css("left", "20%");
                    if (titleid != $text.length - 1) {
                        titleid++;
                    } else {
                        titleid = 0;
                    }
                    setTimeout(fadeText, 0);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

var titleid=0;

$(function () {
  $text = $("span.floating-text");
  $subtext = $("span.floating-subtext");
  fadeText();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. I, however, _hate_ `if`-clauses, so I have replaced this with: `titleid = (titleid + 1) % $text.length;`

Comment: I hadn't understood what you were doing with that percent/modulo operator there. It actually works nicely. Is it more efficient than an if statement? Is that why you don't like if statements or is there another reason? It can also be done on one line with titleid=(titleid==2)?0:titleid+1; but I guess that's just a disguised if statement

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much the main reason. You can't code without ever using an `if`-clause, however if I can prevent it, I will do it differently. It is usually faster as well :)